# Ideal Reheat Rankine Cycle Analysis

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

I'm analyzing an ideal reheat Rankine cycle for a steam power plant operating between the pressure limits of 10 MPa and 10 kPa. The mass flow rate of steam through the cycle is 15 kg/s, and steam enters both the high-pressure (HP) and low-pressure (LP) turbines at 500°C.

I want to determine the total heat input in the boiler in KW and thermal efficiency of the cycle for three different reheater pressures:

(a) 3 MPa
(b) 0.95 MPa
(c) 500 kPa

Can someone guide me through the process of solving this problem for at least one case?
Are there any resources or software recommendations for visualizing T-S diagrams for steam cycles?